# fullepage.js: it is possibile to set different height for the slides that are contained in a specific section

Tags: fullpage.js

I would be set a differente height of viewport of the slides that are contained in a section.
Example: 
I have:

```
<div class="section fp-auto-height">
<div class="slide" id="slide1"> CONTENT </div>
<div class="slide" id="slide2"> CONTENT</div>
<div class="slide" id="slide3"> CONTENT</div>
</div><!-- end section-0-->
```

The content of the slide1 is too long, and I have used the class fp-auto-height for see all the content on mobile, but when I go to the slide2 (that have pour text), I see the height to big because fullpage.js have set the same height of slide1 to slide2.

Can I resolve?

Thank you
Best regards
Mario

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for doesn't make much sense from the design perspective.

You can not slide a bigger section to a smaller one. The slides form the slider has to have the same height.